# How to get objectID field for custom attribute AllowedValues in order to UPDATE/DELETE them?

Tags: rest, rally

I'm trying to **delete AllowedValues from a custom AttributeDefinition**. Based on Rally API docs it's possible to delete AllowedValues:

```
DELETE https://eu1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/allowedattributevalue/ObjectID
```

[REST URLs for AllowedAttributeValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scgKd.png)

But, when you retrieve AllowedValues from an attribute like this:

`https://eu1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/attributedefinition/66370192405/allowedvalues`

The queryresult contains null value for ObjectID for every allowedvalue of the list. How could I obtain these ObjectID for allowedvalues in order to delete them?

```
{
  "QueryResult": {
    "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
    "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
    "Errors": [],
    "Warnings": [],
    "TotalResultCount": 3,
    "StartIndex": 1,
    "PageSize": 20,
    "Results": [
      {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "_ref": "null",
        "_refObjectUUID": "",
        "_objectVersion": "0",
        "CreationDate": null,
     >> "ObjectID": null, <<
        "ObjectUUID": "null",
        "VersionId": "0",
        "AttributeDefinition": {
          "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
          "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
          "_ref": "https://eu1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/attributedefinition/66370192405",
          "_refObjectUUID": "9a44c6d3-2489-46e4-bf2b-01331d526f1a",
          "_refObjectName": "Prioridad2222",
          "_type": "AttributeDefinition"
        },
        "IntegerValue": null,
        "LocalizedStringValue": "aaaa",
        "StringValue": "aaaa",
        "ValueIndex": 0,
        "_type": "AllowedAttributeValue"
      }
…
```

Comment: In fact, when you create via POST a new AllowedAttributeValue you get the ObjectID as a field in the response, but not when you GET AllowedValues from a attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get an answer from Rally support team. This is a reported issue, and there is not going to be a a fix any soon due to internal dependencies. So I guess that the only way, at this moment, to update/delete an allowedvalue via REST API is to store your way its ObjectID at creation time and then use that stored data if you want to update/delete using:

```
DELETE https://eu1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/allowedattributevalue/ObjectID
UPDATE https://eu1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/allowedattributevalue/ObjectID
```

Comment: Obviously this have sense only if you created these allowedvalues via API previously. If not you have to deal with UI to update/delete them.